# A custom variable in config of nginx, in "server", won't get resolved

Tags: nginx

I run nginx. In a "server" section for one of websites I have this:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  set $app_name myapp;
  set $app_port 4000;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$app_name.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$app_name.com/privkey.pem;


  access_log /var/log/nginx/$app_name.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/$app_name.com.error.log;

  #.............
```

At least one of the custom variables won't get resolved - `app_name`; for instance, it'll create a file `/var/log/nginx/$app_name.com.access.log`

namely, with **$app_name** in it.

Consequently, in all other places of the config  file where it's used, it won't get resolved either.

In the "error.log" I see that value of the variable is empty.

Why not? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you get this working somehow you really should not use this method:

> The file path can contain variables (0.7.6+), but such logs have some constraints:
>
> - the user whose credentials are used by worker processes should have permissions to create files in a directory with such logs;
> - buffered writes do not work;
> - the file is opened and closed for each log write. However, since the descriptors of frequently used files can be stored in a cache, writing to the old file can continue during the time specified by the open_log_file_cache directive’s valid parameter
> - [..]

Also the `error_log` does not appear to accept variables at all.

You are better of by using a template/macro language to generate the configs (I prefer m4 for this, see `man m4`).

Comment: where's the quote from?

Comment: from the documentation of the log module http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Answer (score 0):

**Buffered logs** cannot have variables in path!

It seems like *[error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log)* by default is a buffer log.

> Logging to a cyclic memory buffer can be configured by specifying the “memory:” prefix and buffer size, and is generally used for debugging (1.7.11).

So `error_log` won't work with variable defined in path like so:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/$app_name.com.error.log;
```

The same is valid for `access_log` directive with `buffer` or `gzip`parameters defined.

Once you set

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/$app_name.com.access.log buffer flush=5m;
```

it is a buffer log and your variable name won't get resolved. It results in
Nginx's error.

But if you set

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/$app_name.com.access.log;
```

apparently it is not a buffer log and your variable name want get resolved.
That's why one of your custom variable names got resolved.